# Ebean Error when ending a query only transaction via COMMIT

Tags: postgresql, ebean

There's an error in our system which uses ebean for DB communication and queries.

The error we see is this:

```
30/01/2020 INFO 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-8] io.ebean.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool  : DataSourcePool [ftc_central_b] autoCommit[false] transIsolation[READ_COMMITTED] min[2] max[200]
30/01/2020 INFO 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-8] i.e.d.pool.BusyConnectionBuffer          : Dumping [1] busy connections: (Use datasource.xxx.capturestacktrace=true  ... to get stackTraces)
30/01/2020 WARN 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-8] i.e.d.pool.PooledConnectionQueue         : Closing busy connections on shutdown size: 1
30/01/2020 INFO 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-8] i.e.d.pool.BusyConnectionBuffer          : Busy Connection - name[ftc_central_a6811] slot[48] startTime[1580318444092] busySeconds[16] stackTrace[] stmt[<select query>]
30/01/2020 WARN 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-8] i.e.d.pool.BusyConnectionBuffer          : DataSourcePool closing busy connection? name[ftc_central_a6811] slot[48] startTime[1580318444092] busySeconds[16] stackTrace[] stmt[<select query>]
30/01/2020 CLOSING busy connection: name[ftc_central_a6811] slot[48] startTime[1580318444092] busySeconds[16] stackTrace[] stmt[<select query>)]
30/01/2020 ERROR 1 --- [n-db-periodic-1] i.e.server.transaction.JdbcTransaction   : Error when ending a query only transaction via COMMIT
```

We switch from ftc_central_a and ftc_central_b. Is there any config change thatwe can to avoid this situation? I can increase the leakTimeMinutes from 30 to 60, but I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: > We switch from ftc_central_a and ftc_central_b ... ah, datasource pool switch ... probably does not check for "busy connections".

Comment: So maybe ... wait for busy connections to complete before switch OR ... switch but not shutdown pool closing busy connections

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with `datasource.offline()`

Logged as #31 - datasource.offline() closes busy connections ... should let them close on return 
https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean-datasource/issues/31

The fix means that offline() will not close busy connections but instead allow them to continue work and instead they are closed on return to the pool.